# Linq join on a case

Tags: linq, join

I would like to call my join depending on the ProductType.

```
var stocks = (from st in _context.StockDetails
    join p in _context.ProductType1 on p.ProductId equals p.Id
    select new StockList
    {
    ProductId = st.ProductId,
    ProductType = st.ProductType,
    StockValue = st.StockValue,
    InOut = st.InOut,
    ProductName  = p.ProductName 
    });
```

In that case, st.ProductType = ProductType1
But I have also different tables for ProductType2, ProductType3... And want to join the adequate one.

These tables are not identical. They have their specific column and also some common ones. Table ProductType1 for books, ProductType2 for gardening tools,... Of course ProductName is a common column to all (and a few others like weight,...) But I have decided to split these products in different tables and here I am!!!
This process is not at the end.
Strategically, would it be better practice to have them in the same table with specific name fields like String1, String2, Int1, Int2,.... and the common column with proper names like ProductName, Weight,...
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please addd more information. Why you need to join to several identical tables? What is adequate one, which rule for that?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv, I did add some more information (and question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your design I do not see many options. You have to choose which is better for you

**SOLUTION 1**

```
var stocks1 = from st in _context.StockDetails
    join p in _context.ProductType1 on p.ProductId equals p.Id
    where st.ProductType == 1
    select new StockList
    {
        ProductId = st.ProductId,
        ProductType = st.ProductType,
        StockValue = st.StockValue,
        InOut = st.InOut,
        ProductName  = p.ProductName 
    };

var stocks2 = from st in _context.StockDetails
    join p in _context.ProductType2 on p.ProductId equals p.Id
    where st.ProductType == 2
    select new StockList
    {
        ProductId = st.ProductId,
        ProductType = st.ProductType,
        StockValue = st.StockValue,
        InOut = st.InOut,
        ProductName  = p.ProductName 
    };

var stocks3 = from st in _context.StockDetails
    join p in _context.ProductType3 on p.ProductId equals p.Id
    where st.ProductType == 3
    select new StockList
    {
        ProductId = st.ProductId,
        ProductType = st.ProductType,
        StockValue = st.StockValue,
        InOut = st.InOut,
        ProductName  = p.ProductName 
    };

...
var stocks = stocks1.Concat(stocks2).Concat(stocks3);
```

SOLUTION 2

```
var products = 
   _context.ProductType1.Select(p => new { ProductType = 1, p.ProductId, p.ProductName })
   .Concat(context.ProductType2.Select(p => new { ProductType = 2, p.ProductId, p.ProductName }))
   .Concat(context.ProductType3.Select(p => new { ProductType = 3, p.ProductId, p.ProductName }));

var stocks = from st in _context.StockDetails
    join p in products on new { st.ProductType, st.ProductId } equals new { p.ProductType, p.ProductId }
    select new StockList
    {
        ProductId = st.ProductId,
        ProductType = st.ProductType,
        StockValue = st.StockValue,
        InOut = st.InOut,
        ProductName  = p.ProductName 
    };
```

SOLUTION 3

```
var stocks = from st in _context.StockDetails
    join p1 in _context.ProductType1 on new { st.ProductType, st.ProductId } equals new { ProductType = 1, p1.ProductId } into j
    from p1 in j.DefaultIfEmpty()
    join p2 in _context.ProductType1 on new { st.ProductType, st.ProductId } equals new { ProductType = 2, p2.ProductId } into j
    from p2 in j.DefaultIfEmpty()
    join p3 in _context.ProductType3 on new { st.ProductType, st.ProductId } equals new { ProductType = 3, p3.ProductId } into j
    from p3 in j.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new StockList
    {
        ProductId = st.ProductId,
        ProductType = st.ProductType,
        StockValue = st.StockValue,
        InOut = st.InOut,
        ProductName  = p1.ProductName ?? p2.ProductName ?? p3.ProductName
    };
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @SvyatoslavDanyliv. I will try all of them :-)
Around 30% of the columns are specific, the rest is common. Would it be better to migrate all the products in one table even though its getting larger (maybe 150 columns all together)? Because I will run into this problem more than once.
What do you think?

Comment: If there will be 150 columns it is a bad idea. Maybe you have to choose TPT (Table Per Type) which should be supported by EF Core 5. I don't know how it performs, but I think bad ;). Anyway, for example ,Solution 3 can be written once in common function and then used in other queries.